# how to port forward to middleware with nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I am running a web application on linux (ubuntu 16.4) and everything works fine but I need to forward requests to mydomain.com/api to port 3000. Can someone explain in detail about how to do this with nginx? I am using vhost record (built in to ubunutu to host the site, but right now when the requests point to mysite.com:3000/api some people are saying that the requests are not working especially on corporate environments etc. My suspicion is that I am specifying the port in the api.

For an example please go to [www.skoolaide.com](http://www.skoolaide.com) and try to create an account.

I have searched the web but its not very clear on how to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your nginx vhost like

```
server {
     listen       80;
     location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     }
 }
```

so that all incoming requests to port 80 will be proxied to port 3000

Comment: can you provide a complete explanation on how to set this up etc? I have never used nginx, also will it override my virtualhost file/

Comment: also what if I just want requests for mywebsite.com/api to point to 3000

Comment: @JudsonTerrell let's go to chat. This is really off topic for stackoverflow

Comment: how do we go to chat?